# Jenkins/ MacOS - dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect:permission denied

Tags: macos, docker, unix, jenkins

i am new to using jenkins and docker. Currently I ran into an error where my jenkinsfile doesnt have permission to docker.sock. Is there a way to fix this? Dried out of ideas

things i've tried:

-`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`     //usermod not found

-`sudo setfacl --modify user:******:rw /var/run/docker.sock` //setfacl not found

-`chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` //still receiving this error after reboot

-`chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/run/docker.sock` //changing ownership of '/var/run/docker.sock': Operation not permitted

error image:
[image]

```
def gv

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
        VERSION = "$BUILD_NUMBER"
        PROJECT = "foodcore"
        IMAGE = "$PROJECT:$VERSION"
    }
    tools {
        nodejs "node"
        'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool' 'docker'
    }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'VERSION', choices: ['1.1.0', '1.2.0', '1.3.0'], description: '')
        booleanParam(name: 'executeTests', defaultValue: true, description: '')
    }
    stages {
        stage("init") {
            steps {
                script {
                   gv = load "script.groovy"
                   CODE_CHANGES = gv.getGitChanges()
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build frontend") {
            steps {
                dir("client") {
                    sh 'npm install'
                    echo 'building client'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build backend") {
            steps {
                dir("server") {
                    sh 'npm install'
                    echo 'building server...'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("build docker image") {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t $IMAGE .'
            }
        }
        // stage("deploy") {
        //     steps {
        //         script {
        //             docker.withRegistry(ECURL, ECRCRED) {
        //                 docker.image(IMAGE).push()
        //             }
        //         }
        //     }
        // }
    }
    // post {
    //     always {
    //         sh "docker rmi $IMAGE | true"
    //     }
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

docker.sock permissions will be lost if you restart system or docker service.

To make it persistence setup a cron to change ownership after each reboot

```
@reboot chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

and When you restart the docker, make sure to run the below command

```
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Or you can put a cron for it also, which will execute in each every 5 minutes.